# No module named ... in PyCharm (import error)

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm on MAC to import some packages by

```
import pymongo
import bson
```

However the error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'`

The packages are installed successfully and there is nothing wrong when running them in the command line
I also checked the Interpreter Configuration in Pycharm, fixed to Python 3.6(my only version of Python 3)

Also, when I use `pip3 freeze` it indicates that these packages are successfully installed

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running Python in a virtual environment (venv), the packages you installed via pip cannot be found in this environment.

At the project interpreter, click the plus (+) sign at the bottom and add your packages there.

[image: Project interpreter]

Click the + at the bottom

[image: Install package]
Search for, and install your package

Answer (score 0):

Delete the venv folder and then add the interpreter again from Settings>Project Interpreter. 
After that add the packages again(pip install package-name)