# Python "no module named" error in the python console

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have installed numpy and requests though pip install. I open Pycharm and type in the console:

```
import requests
```

or

```
import numpy
```

I get:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I find many solutions to the problem online but with local packages and relative imports. How do I solve in this very simple case? I am using python 3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named ... in PyCharm (import error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093363/no-module-named-in-pycharm-import-error)

Comment: Try doing a re-install on the requests package? pip install requests --force-reinstall

Comment: Install package from inside pycharm

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm provides a tool for installing, uninstalling, and upgrading Python packages:

Step 1 : **Project Settings** > **Project Interpreter**

Step 2 : **Select** the desired **Python interpreter** (or virtual environment)

Step 3 : **Click** on the **+** button (the available Packagesdialog box opens)

Step 4 : **Select** the desired **package** from the list and **click** on **Install Package**

If you install a Python package through pip install, there are **not** (by default) available in PyCharm.