# Pycharm : package Pycurl installed but not found (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, module, pycharm, package, pycurl

I installed pycurl for python3
but when I want to import it to Pycharm and use it I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cours/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pycurl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycurl'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cours/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pycurl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycurl'
```

But when I install it with the Pycharm terminal (pip install pycurl) I get this message

```
Requirement already satisfied: pycurl in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (7.43.0.1)
```

I also already imported the package with : Settings -> Python Interpreter

And finally i also used : "Inherit global site-package" option of the project and the problem is the same

I have no idea what else i can do

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093363/no-module-named-in-pycharm-import-error)

Comment: Didn't change anything

Comment: You restarted the application?

Comment: Delete the venv folder and then add the interpreter again from Settings>Project Interpreter. After that add the packages again(pip install package-name)

Comment: Yes i just did that and got an error message

Answer (score 0):

use command this command to install package -

pip3 install pycurl

and also check the Pycharm python version in for code compile

Comment: It's python 3.7, and when i use this command : pip3 install pycurl just after creating a new project i get :   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: ....

Comment: if you can do that you can reinstall python3 if pip3 install ... command is not working

Comment: The problem is not python but pycharm, i can launch the program with the terminal, 
I just reinstalled Pychar, and got the same issue, but i can install other modules like pygame